# How can I quickly tell a multisession DVD from a single-session one?

Tags: dvd, dvd-burning

I burn a lot of DVDs over multiple sessions, and I tend to forget which discs are multisessioned and which aren't. Is there any way to tell them apart, without having to check them in a disc drive?

Comment: You label all your discs with a Sharpie or something, right? Couldn't you just put some kind of mark on multisession discs, and a different one on single-session discs? Maybe just an `M` for multisession.

Comment: You should be labeling all your discs anyway, one way or another. Otherwise distinguishing multisession vs. single-session won't be the only problem you'll have. ;)